# Sending a generic type from Client to Server

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a simple client that sends data to the web api server through a generic type

The following structure exists on both server and client

```
public interface IRequest<T>
{
    string ApiKey { get; set; }
    T RequestObject { get; set; }
}

public class UserRequest : IRequest<UserDetail>
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public UserDetail RequestObject { get; set; }
}
```

I send a request to the server using the following syntax

```
var client = new RestClient(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUri"]);
var profileRequest = new UserRequest
            {
                ApiKey = "xxxxx",
                RequestObject = new UserDetail {Password = txtPassword.Text, UserName = txtUserName.Text}
            };
 var request = new RestRequest("UserRequest/PostUserDetail", Method.POST);
 request.AddObject(profileRequest);
```

Now the interesting thing is that on the Server side, the UserDetail object does not get de-serialised properly, it just contains NULL, the ApiKey property is set correctly though

```
 public UserDetail PostUserDetail(UserRequest userRequest)
    {
        return new UserDetail { Password = userRequest.RequestObject.Password, UserName = userRequest.RequestObject.UserName };
    }
```

from the above, userRequest.ApiKey is set, however, userRequest.RequestObject is always NULL on the server API

Are generic types not supported? if not, does anyone have any pointers as to how I could modify the Deserializer on the server side? I have checked to see if the object is constructed properly on the client side and it is.

Many Thanks

Comment: I think that whatever type you use for RequestObject has to be marked with the [Serializeable] attribute (and also actually be serializeable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Web Api scenario is supported.  I have tried repro'ing your WebAPI by creating a UserRequest ApiController with PostUserDetail, and I was able to get the expected 'Password' and 'UserName' in the response:

```
Request Content:
{"ApiKey":"123","RequestObject":{"Password":"bar","UserName":"foo"}}

Response Content:
{"Password":"bar","UserName":"foo"}
```

On the client side, I would recommend you to use HttpClient instead.  Here is my client repro:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = new ObjectContent<UserRequest>(profileRequest, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        var response2 = httpClient.PostAsync(addr, content).Result; // using .Result here for simplicity...
        Console.WriteLine(response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: Thanks Maggie, I was able to use fiddler to play your request content to confirm that Web Api does indeed handle this scenario. I was using the RestSharp library inappropriately, after downloading the source code, I realized that I have to use request.AddBody(profileRequest) as opposed to  request.AddObject(profileRequest); to add the type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the Content-Type header to the service?. From you code above, I see that you are not supplying Content-Type header. In the case of absence of Content-Type header, Web Api generates the default value of the type(which would be NULL for UserRequest).